# Enter two inputs, fill the third

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I've got a form with three inputs. I want to be able to fill out two of the fields and automaticly fill the third field.

So, it should work like this:
  - I fill out the first and second, the third gets calculated
  - I fill out the first and last, the second gets calculated
  - I fill out the second and last, the first gets calculated

I came up with this code:

```js
$(document).on('keyup change', '[data-calc]', function() {
 var a = $('[data-calc=a]') ,
    aV = a.val() ,
      b = $('[data-calc=b]') ,
      bV = b.val() ,
      c = $('[data-calc=c]') ,
      cV = c.val();
  if(aV.length != 0 && bV.length != 0) {
   cV = parseInt(aV) + parseInt(bV);
   c.val(cV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else if(aV.length != 0 && cV.length != 0) {
   bV = parseInt(cV) - parseInt(aV);
   b.val(bV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else if(bV.length != 0 && cV.length != 0) {
   aV = parseInt(cV) - parseInt(bV);
   a.val(aV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else {
   $('[data-calc]').prop('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-calc="a" /><br />
+<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="b" /><br />
=<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="c" />
```

Now the works fine when I fill out the first and second field.

But if I fill out the first, and the third after that, the third field gets disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: `b.val(bV).prop('disabled',true);` will disable second input...Which field you want to be disabled ?

Comment: I guess this is how it should be...https://jsfiddle.net/7bz3jz2z/

Comment: The double binding was the problem. Details in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be, you should check which element was edited

```js
$(document).on('keyup change', '[data-calc]', function(event) {
  var $this = $(event.target || event.srcElement),
    calc = $this.data('calc'),
    $newCalc,
    $a,
    $b,
    $c,
    aV,
    bV,
    cV;
  if (!calc) {
    return;
  }

  $a = $('input[data-calc=a]');
  $b = $('input[data-calc=b]');
  $c = $('input[data-calc=c]');

  $('input[data-calc]').prop('disabled', false);

  aV = Number($a.val());
  bV = Number($b.val());
  cV = Number($c.val());

  if (calc === 'a') {
    if (!!aV && !!bV) {
      $newCalc = $c.val(aV + bV);
    } else if (!!aV && !!cV) {
      $newCalc = $b.val(cV - aV);
    }
  } else if (calc === 'b') {
    if (!!aV && !!bV) {
      $newCalc = $c.val(aV + bV);
    } else if (!!bV && !!cV) {
      $newCalc = $a.val(cV - bV);
    }
  } else if (calc === 'c') {
    if (!!aV && !!cV) {
      $newCalc = $b.val(cV - aV);
    } else if (!!bV && !!cV) {
      $newCalc = $a.val(cV - bV);
    }
  }
  if ($newCalc) { $newCalc.prop('disabled', true); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-calc="a" />
<br />+
<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="b" />
<br />=
<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="c" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in you double binding to both `keyup` & `change` events. Remove the `change` from your code and you're set to go :-)

When you type a value into the 3rd field, first the `keyup` event fired, and all was well, and when the focus moved out of the 3rd field it fired the `change` event- which in turn disabled it since the 1st & 2nd fields both had values.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '[data-calc]', function() {
 var a = $('[data-calc=a]') ,
    aV = a.val() ,
      b = $('[data-calc=b]') ,
      bV = b.val() ,
      c = $('[data-calc=c]') ,
      cV = c.val();
  if(aV.length != 0 && bV.length != 0) {
   cV = parseInt(aV) + parseInt(bV);
   c.val(cV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else if(aV.length != 0 && cV.length != 0) {
   bV = parseInt(cV) - parseInt(aV);
   b.val(bV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else if(bV.length != 0 && cV.length != 0) {
   aV = parseInt(cV) - parseInt(bV);
   a.val(aV).prop('disabled',true);
  }
  else {
   $('[data-calc]').prop('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-calc="a" /><br />
+<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="b" /><br />
=<br />
<input type="text" data-calc="c" />
```

Comment: It works. Again, the problem is the two digit you enter in the bottom field. after the first digit (1), you get the logic, and then on the secont `keyup`, you already have values in the top & middle fields. I would suggest changing the event to `blur`, and avoid the pre-mature calculation... anyway, the downvote isn't cool :-)